# writing a bash script that deletes a variable in another file

Tags: linux, bash

OK so I asked the question how to add a variable to the end of a line in another file last night and got GREAT answers, thanks for that by the way!
Now I want to do the reverse.
I am writing a bash script that basically undoes what I did with the first.  As part of that I have the same variable and now I want to remove it from another file, this time it could be anywhere in that file and I just want to remove it without changing the file or breaking the line it is in.  Not even sure where to start on this one but.  Say I have

```
echo -e "Enter inside IP address to be Removed: \c"
read inside_ip
```

now I need a command that removes `$inside_ip` from file `list-of-ips` which is a single line of IPs like

```
1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3 ...
```

Comment: `sed` to the rescue, would be simper to give a good answer if you provided some before and after example... `sed -i` does the changes inline, i.e. storing the changes in the affected file.

Comment: sorry, I am collecting a few variables and doing other stuff with them.  On the other script I am doing this to add the value for inside_ip to the file  sed -i.bck '$s/$/ '"$inside_ip:80/" list-of-prod-ips  Now I want to remove a value that is put in there.  The difference now is that the IP that I am trying to remove could be anywhere in the file.  It could be the first IP or the 25th IP.  The file is just a list of IPs in a line without any returns.  So if you vi the file it is one line.

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear but this should get you started:

```
$ cat input
1.1.1
2.2.2
3.3.3
4.4.4
5.5.5

$ ip='3.3.3'

$ sed "/$ip/d" input
1.1.1
2.2.2
4.4.4
5.5.5
```

Note the `"` quotation in the sed command above, `"` allow the shell to perform parameter expansion, if you instead used single-quotes `'`, sed would look for the literal string `$ip` and you don't want that.

Use `sed -i` to make the changes inline

Answer (score 0):

As fredrik mentioned, use of sed will work but I would use the following since your results are all on one line...

Suppose file **foo.txt** contains the following:

```
1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3 4.4.4.4
```

You could use the following to remove your ip:

```
ip="3.3.3.3"
sed -i 's/\b'$ip'\b//g' foo.txt
```

Results would be:

```
1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2  4.4.4.4
```

This will remove the matches globally within the line (in case you have multiple matches).  Also keep in mind that the dots in the ip address mean any character match in regex so there is the small potential to have an unexpected match.  You can place backslashes in your ip variable to avoid it if needed.